# Ignore . (dot) directories in os.walk

Tags: python, recursion, os.walk

Learning a python I'm working on a generic utility script to recurse any directories below and spit filenames and other properties into a file - on Windows right now. I keep getting errors as below and I don't care about these files which appear to be found in "dot directories" so far. Manually listing directories to directories.remove() is fun whack-a-mole but I need better. I can't figure out how to just tell it to ignore all dot directories.

```
    file_size = os.path.getsize(filename)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\genericpath.py", line 50, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'COMMIT_EDITMSG'
```

Here's where I am

```
import os
import time

# pip install --user hurry.filesize
from hurry.filesize import size

path = "./"

for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(path):
    if ".*" in directories:
        directories.remove(".*")

    for filename in filenames:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
        file_size = os.path.getsize(filename)
        better_changetime = time.strftime(
            "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(filename))
        )
        fprops = file_path + " | " + better_changetime + " | " + size(file_size)
        print(fprops)
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it has anything to do with dot directories. This looks like you're screwing up your path manipulation, trying to call `getsize` on the bare filename (and `".*"` doesn't act like a glob, and probably more wrong things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filename patterns are not processed by the `in` operator or the `.remove()` method. You can use the `filter()` function to remove names that match a pattern.

```
directories = filter(lambda name: not name.startswith("."), function)
```

But you never use `directories` later, so I'm not sure what the point of this is. Removing directories from this list won't remove the files that are within them from the `filenames` list.

The error is because you're using `filename` rather than `file_path` when you call `os.path.getsize()` and `os.path.getmtime()`.

Comment: Python lists don't have a `filter` method. You might be mixing things up with a different language.

Comment: I always get it confused with JS.

Comment: @Barmar, my scripts are throwing errors on files mostly contained in dot directories (.git, .ipynb_checkpoints for example) and I don't care about those files. So I thought I would exclude these directories to solve multiple problems. Your help resolved this error! But it highlights that I still want to exclude some directories with something like a wildcard because I now see items like "/__pycache__\pylustrator.cpython-37.pyc" and I probably don't want items from directories that startswith("__") either.

Comment: You can use `re.search()` to test against a pattern.